# How to populate dropdown options dynamically using a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

```
import { getCustomer } from './Customers';
let optionItems=[];

export const LOV: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const loadCustomer = async () => {
  const data = await getCustomer();
  for (var i=0; i < data.value.length ; ++i)
  {
   optionItems.push({
    key: data.value[i].CustomerId,
    text: data.value[i].CustomerName
  });
 }
}
useEffect(() => {
 loadCustomer();
}, [])

return (
  <SearchableDropdown options={optionItems}/>    
);};
```

**Code in Customers.tsx**

```
export const getCustomer = async (): Promise<any> => {
const response = await 
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    type: "GET",
    headers: headers,
    data: null,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + accessToken); 
    }
})
.done( function (data) {
    return data;
})
.fail(function (jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
        promptAuth(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("WWW-Authenticate"));
    } 
    else {
        console.log("NOT 401");
    }
});  
return response;
}
```

I'm trying to populate a dropdown dynamically using a promise. I'm using Fluent-react Dropdown. getCustomer() loads values to const data. However, I can't see any values in the dropdown even though data is not null. Please help.

Fluent Dropdown =>  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `optionsItems` need to be reactive. Try using `useState`-hook

```
export const LOV: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [optionItems, setOptionItems] = useState([]);
  const loadCustomer = async () => {
  const data = await getCustomer();
  const options = [];
  for (var i=0; i < data.value.length ; ++i)
  {
   options.push({
    key: data.value[i].CustomerId,
    text: data.value[i].CustomerName
  });
 }
 setOptionItems(options)
}
useEffect(() => {
 loadCustomer();
}, [])

return (
  <SearchableDropdown options={optionItems}/>    
);};
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution. Now the whole page is blank and I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase'). Do you know why? :(

Comment: Post the whole code where ` TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')` happend

Comment: I didn't use toLowerCase anywhere in the code. I updated the question to show getCustomer(). These files do not contain any other code

Comment: @Intern is your customerId null or undefined? It needs to be a string value

Comment: Hi @Stuje I tried your solution after stringifying the data and it worked! thank you so much!! since I entered [ text: JSON.stringify(data.value[i].CustomerName) ] all the values in the dropdown are seen inside a double quotation mark ( "Customer name"). Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: const stringWithQuotes = "\"text\""
const stringWithoutQuotes = stringWithQuotes.replaceAll("\"", "")
Note that with this approach even when you will try to use " in your string, it will get replaced

Comment: Hi @deaponn, I tried JSON.stringify(data.value[i].CustomerName.replaceAll("\"", "")). But it didn't work. i tried JSON.stringify(data.value[i].CustomerName).replaceAll("\"", "") and got errors :( please help

Comment: You need to follow the instructions carefully: first get the string from your object like so: const stringWithQuotes = data.value[i].CustomerName, then continue as above. There is no need to use JSON.stringify for strings, as data.value[i].CustomerName is a string already. By the way this is why you have quotes around your words. Just use <div>{data.value[i].CustomerName}</div> and not <div>{JSON.stringify(data.value[i].CustomerName)}</div>

Comment: Hi I can't use <div> tags inside as it conflicts with fluent IDropdownOptions. I tried  `${data.value[i].CustomerName}` and it worked! thank you all for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure your `data.value[i].CustomerId` and `data.value[i].CustomerName` are valid strings. You need to supply string, but it looks like your API call returns null there. After you fix this problem, together with Stutje's solution your app should start to work.